# Number Of Mappers Spawned In Pig And Hive

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, apache-pig

I have a partitioned table in hive where each partition will have 630 gzip compressed files each of average size 100kb. If I query over these files using hive it will generate exactly 630 mappers i.e one mapper for one file.
 Now as an experiment i tried reading those files with pig and pig actually combined the files and spawned only 2 mappers and the operation was much faster than hive. 
Why is there a difference in execution style of pig and hive? In hive can we similarly combine small files to spawn less mappers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify that you want to use the [`CombineHiveInputFormat`](http://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r0.12.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/io/CombineHiveInputFormat.html):

```
set hive.input.format=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat;
```

You should also set the min split size higher:

```
set mapred.min.split.size=100000000;
```

As a side note, the CombineHiveInputFormat is the default Hive input format on EMR for exactly this reason (many small files), see [How Amazon EMR Hive Differs from Apache Hive](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-hive-differences.html).

Pig does the combine because is on by default, see [Combine Small Input Files](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/perf.html#combine-files):

> `pig.splitCombination` – Turns combine split files on or off (set to “true” by default).